# Select first or random row in group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query using PostgreSQL 9.1 (9.2 as soon as our hosting platform upgrades):

```
SELECT
    media_files.album,
    media_files.artist,
    ARRAY_AGG (media_files. ID) AS media_file_ids
FROM
    media_files
INNER JOIN playlist_media_files ON media_files.id = playlist_media_files.media_file_id
WHERE
    playlist_media_files.playlist_id = 1
GROUP BY
    media_files.album,
    media_files.artist
ORDER BY
    media_files.album ASC
```

and it's working fine, the goal was to extract album/artist combinations and in the result set have an array of media files ids for that particular combo.

The problem is that I have another column in media files, which is `artwork`.

`artwork` is unique for each media file (even in the same album) but in the result set I need to return just the first of the set.

So, for an album that has 10 media files, I also have 10 corresponding artworks, but I would like just to return the first (or a random picked one for that collection).

Is that possible to do with only SQL/Window Functions (first_value over..)?

Comment: Your query would be MUCH easier to read if you aliased `media_files` and `playlist_media_files` and then qualified references to their columns. Otherwise how do we know which table `album` and `artist` come from without the table definitions? Also, please always mention your PostgreSQL version in questions.

Comment: You are right, just very tired, I added pgsql version and edited the query to include table names. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. First, let's tweak your query by adding alias and explicit column qualifiers so it's clear what comes from where - assuming I've guessed correctly, since I can't be sure without table definitions:

```
SELECT
    mf.album,
    mf.artist,
    ARRAY_AGG (mf.id) AS media_file_ids
FROM
    "media_files" mf
INNER JOIN "playlist_media_files" pmf ON mf.id = pmf.media_file_id
WHERE
    pmf.playlist_id = 1
GROUP BY
    mf.album,
    mf.artist
ORDER BY
    mf.album ASC
```

Now you can either use a subquery in the `SELECT` list or maybe use [`DISTINCT ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT), though it looks like any solution based on `DISTINCT ON` will be so convoluted as not to be worth it.

What you really want is something like an `pick_arbitrary_value_agg` aggregate that just picks the first value it sees and throws the rest away. There is no such aggregate and it isn't really worth implementing it for the job. You could use `min(artwork)` or `max(artwork)` and you may find that this actually performs better than the later solutions.

To use a subquery, leave the `ORDER BY` as it is and add the following as an extra column in your `SELECT` list:

```
(SELECT mf2.artwork 
 FROM media_files mf2 
 WHERE mf2.artist = mf.artist
   AND mf2.album = mf.album
 LIMIT 1) AS picked_artwork
```

You can at a performance cost randomize the selected artwork by adding `ORDER BY random()` before the `LIMIT 1` above.

Alternately, here's a quick and dirty way to implement selection of a random row in-line:

```
(array_agg(artwork))[width_bucket(random(),0,1,count(artwork)::integer)]
```

Since there's no sample data I can't test these modifications. Let me know if there's an issue.

Comment: I'm attempting the select distinct solution with this final query: http://pastie.org/private/oiip78vp1fjgfxkam2i8tw but it returns an error `column "mf.album" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` I'm doing something wrong for sure or I still not fully understand what's going on here. Need to look up some documentation still. Thanks for any hints.

Comment: mm missed the group by, hold on.. :P

Comment: @kain You left out the `GROUP BY` clause from your original query.

Comment: ok, so, I updated the pastie to include the group by, however I get another error along the lines of the previous saying that mf.artwork (field is called artwork_path in reality, but it's not important now) should be part of the group by. If I put this field in the group by the results are off: http://cl.ly/image/3X1720310E01

Comment: @kain My mistake, you're clearly not the only muddled one. `DISTINCT ON` won't work here, try the subquery.

Comment: it's my understanding however that the subquery scans the entire table and not limit itself to the current result set? it works but it takes 60 seconds, I perhaps need to limit this to the current results, because of other users/playlists that may have custom artworks. Thanks.

Comment: @kain You're correct in that it'll hit the table again. If you have an index on `media_files(album, artist)` that should be fairly OK. Otherwise use an aggregate like `max(artwork)` or `min(artwork)`. Sadly there's no `arbitrary_agg(..)` or `random_agg(...)` . You could implement one fairly easily in PL/PgSQL but I won't be surprised if a subquery with appropriate indexes is way faster.

Comment: @kain Try `(array_agg(artwork))[width_bucket(random(),0,1,count(artwork)::integer)] ` ; that should perform pretty well if you have relatively sane numbers of rows in each aggregate bucket and uses only the scanned result set, it doesn't require additional table access or indexes.

Comment: the `width_bucket` solution is very fast, thanks. I have troubles understanding however 'where' or from which result set postgresql is grabbing it :) edit: oh I saw the edit, very nice, thank you! Time to dig more docs.

Comment: @kain Break the expression down step-by-step. What it does is create two aggregates as it scans the table: one that's an array of every matching `artwork`, and another that's the count of how many `artwork`s there are. After aggregation, during final processing of the `SELECT` list functions, it scales a random number between 0 and 1 out to `count(artwork)` size and uses that scaled random number as an index into the generated array of `artwork`s. `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` might be informative. I haven't verified that the random number range is correct; check for possible off-by-one error.

Comment: Proposal for the random pick: `(array_agg(artwork))[floor(random() * count(*))::int)]`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I'm pretty sure that'll never pick the last entry in the array, because the random result will essentially always be less than `1` so the result will never be equal to count(*). That's why I used `width_bucket` instead, though I'm not totally sure my logic for width_bucket is bang on either, haven't thought about it much.

Comment: Oh, it needs a +1:
`(array_agg(artwork))[floor(random() * count(*))::int + 1)]`. It's actually counting on it, that `random()` never yields 1. I checked: `random value in the range 0.0 <= x < 1.0`. so this should be *flawless*.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Had a quick look at the docs. `random()` is defined to return `random value in the range 0.0 <= x < 1.0` ... so it can't return `1`. Peachy.

Comment: We did that in parallel once again. :)

Answer (score 3):

#### "First" pick

Wouldn't it be simpler / cheaper to just use `min()`:

```
SELECT m.album
      ,m.artist
      ,array_agg(m.id) AS media_file_ids
      ,min(m.artwork)  AS artwork
FROM   playlist_media_files p
JOIN   media_files          m ON m.id = p.media_file_id
WHERE  p.playlist_id = 1
GROUP  BY m.album, m.artist
ORDER  BY m.album, m.artist;
```

#### Abitrary / random pick

If you are looking for a *random* selection, [@Craig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13853656/939860) already provided a solution with truly random picks.

You could also use a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) to avoid additional scans on the (possibly big) base table and then run two separate (cheap) subqueries on the small result set.

For **arbitrary** selection - not truly random, the result will depend on the physical order of rows in the table and implementation-specifics:

```
WITH x AS (
   SELECT m.album, m.artist, m.id, m.artwork
   FROM   playlist_media_files p
   JOIN   media_files          m ON m.id = p.media_file_id
   )
SELECT a.album, a.artist, a.media_file_ids, b.artwork
FROM  (
   SELECT album, artist, array_agg(id) AS media_file_ids
   FROM   x
   ) a
JOIN  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (1,2)  album, artist, artwork
   FROM x
   ) b USING (album, artist);
```

For **truly random** results, you can add an `ORDER BY .. random()` like this to subquery `b`:

```
JOIN  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (1, 2)  album, artist, artwork
   FROM   x
   ORDER  BY 1, 2, random()
   ) b USING (album, artist);
```

Comment: Yep, I suggested that in the answer and comments, but that doesn't cater for a random selection.

Comment: @CraigRinger: The question says: `but I would like just to return the first (or a random picked one for that collection)`, so the "first" is the first choice per definition here? Or is the question just outdated / badly phrased?

Comment: Hard to say; I covered both options since random selection seemed likely to be desirable. I could've been clearer that `min` was the easy option for selecting the least (not necessarily first) result, though.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, English is not my first language, however yes, even this solution will work and @CraigRinger also mentioned it in his post, I just needed few minutes to experiment. Wish I can accept both solutions. Thanks both for the support.